# How to show kubernetes logs in Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I run terraform with kubernetes_pod module, but it fails with "the server could not find the requested resource (post pods)". How can I get more meaningful error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the terraform log to debug or trace like this :

```
export TF_LOG=DEBUG
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/debugging.html

Comment: Can it be enabled only for a particular provider? Only kubernetes for example?